I am getting Missing ';' before argument in function 'Between' at position 1 ( Line 9 ).(IES 10062) error again and again in SAP BO
I am working with "SAP BusinessObjects" and have the following Problem.
When writing a formula, I receive the following error:

Missing ';' before argument in function 'Between' at position 1 ( Line 9 ).(IES 10062)

Below is the code I am working on to find some relevant data:
=[InsertedDate] Between
(
   ToDate(FormatDate(
       If (DayNumberOfWeek(CurrentDate()) = 1) Then
           RelativeDate(CurrentDate(); -3)
       Else
           RelativeDate(CurrentDate(); -1)
   ; "yyyyMMdd") + " 12:00:00"; "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss")
)
And
(
   ToDate(FormatDate(CurrentDate(); "yyyyMMdd") + " 14:29:59"; "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss")
)

Any ideas please?
I tried to add the semi column and close the argument as instructed; nothing worked.

Based on the doc :
The If() function is useful in extending the functionality and flexibility of calculations in reports so that they behave more dynamically.
=If([object name] = "true value" ; [measure] behavior A ; [measure] behavior B)

Or
=If [object name] = "true value" Then [measure] behavior A Else [measure] behavior B

so your code should be :
=[InsertedDate] Between 
ToDate(FormatDate(If(DayNumberOfWeek(CurrentDate()) = 1; RelativeDate(CurrentDate(); -3); RelativeDate(CurrentDate(); -1)); "yyyyMMdd") + " 12:00:00"; "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss")
And
ToDate(FormatDate(CurrentDate(); "yyyyMMdd") + " 14:29:59"; "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss")

Use semicolons to separate arguments in functions, not commas and your IF wasn't properly defined.

Nop it still gives you error of " Missing or bad operand in 'Between' expression at position 1 ( Line 2 ). (IES 10070)"
adding the operands for between doesn't fix the same

Can you breakdowns the expressions and confirm they return valid date objects ?

yes they are returning correct values when I break them out So basically two conditions I am trying to join.
Start: previous* day at 12:00:00 pm
End : Today at 14:29:59pm
If today is monday then previous day should be friday
Separately they are giving the right values but when I use between it gives me error

Start Date Logic
=ToDate(FormatDate(
If (DayNumberOfWeek(CurrentDate()) = 1;
RelativeDate(CurrentDate(); -3);
RelativeDate(CurrentDate(); -1));
"yyyyMMdd") + " 12:00:00"; "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss")
END DATE LOGIC
=ToDate(FormatDate(CurrentDate(); "yyyyMMdd") + " 14:29:59"; "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss")

What tool are using Crystal Reports or Web Intelligence?
